# How to get WooCommerce to send a "Processed" email notification to admin and customer following credit card payment

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

When a customer makes a payment via credit card on my website (funo.co.za), WooCommerce sets the order status to "Pending Payment" by default; and, in result, no order confirmation email is sent to either admin or customer (unless I manually set the status to "Processing").

How do I then set the default status to "Processing" when the payment is made by credit card? The "Processing" status will then automatically send an order email confirmation to admin and customer, as it does when the payment is made using a method of payment other than credit card.

Comment: That is not normal… Your payment gateway should set the status to processing after a successful payment… So you should contact the plugin authors of this payment gateway.

Comment: Hi there Loic... The authors are unfortunately not very helpful when it comes to fixing their work.